# Using Spring AMQP onMessage() method within Flume Lifecycle

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, flume, spring-rabbit

I need to listen to a Rabbit Queue in the Flume Custom Source which I have developed.This requirement may seem awkward in Flume.But this is how its needed.
As I am using Spring AMQP to listen to the queue for simplicity,I am just not able to understand how to invoke the OnMessage() method within the Flume lifecycle Start() method,So that the messages can be posted onto the Flume channel.
I have looked at the Spring MessageListenerAdapter concept but I have not been able to find any example to implement the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onMessage()` is a part of `MessageListener` pattern. It is some active component, which is initiated by the external system (from big height). And it works each time by that remote command, so you can't use it as a `passive` componet to be initiated by the user call.

Since you have "Flume lifecycle Start()" from other side and `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` has the same from its side, I'd say you have to correlate their lifecycles to work in tandem.

From here you should to provide for the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` some inline `MessageListener` implementation, which invokes the desired method to "post onto the Flume channel".

HTH

**UPDATE**

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
....
container.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

   public void onMessage(Message message) {
       sendMessageToFlumeChannel(message);
   }

});
```

Where the `sendMessageToFlumeChannel` is a method of the holding class.

Of course it can be any POJO instead of `MessageListener` implementation, but the main goal to delegate listener resul to some method.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.Could you please elaborate on the inline MessageListener implementation?Do you mean a custom MessageListener?

Comment: Added some simple sample